# Wrong styleable resource value resolved for app compiled with Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

We encounter a strange problem since we've upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 (with Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0).

Our app uses the [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) library. Before AS 3.0 everything worked fine. Now after we migrated the project to AS 3.0 and compile the app with this version of Android Studio and the related Gradle plugin the app crashes when MaterialEditText components are used:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_clear_search_api_holo_dark.png
   at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:304)
   at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.getCustomTypeface(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java:488)
   at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.init(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java:385)
   at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.<init>(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java:325)
     ... 40 more
```

It seems that `typedArray.getString(R.styleable.MaterialEditText_met_accentTypeface)` suddenly resolves to some random drawable path in `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` line [383](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/rengwuxian/materialedittext/MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.java#L383). However this **only** happens on devices with Android **lower than 8.0**. On Android 8.0 the app runs fine.

Our styles have not been changed during the upgrade to AS 3.0:

```
<item name="met_typeface">fonts/UnitRoundedOT.otf</item>
<item name="met_accentTypeface">fonts/UnitRoundedOT.otf</item>
```

Please also see the related [issue](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/issues/346) of the MaterialEditText library.

When migrating an Android project to AS 3.0 it seems that solely using the new Gradle plugin

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

without changing the rest of the Gradle files suffices to provoke this error. A fully migrated project however also has this problem.

Can this be a bug of the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a workaround of this issue is to place the paths to font files in string resources and reference these resources from the style attributes

strings.xml:

```
<string name="font_unit_rounded">fonts/UnitRoundedOT.otf</string>
```

styles.xml:

```
<item name="met_typeface">@string/font_unit_rounded</item>
<item name="met_accentTypeface">@string/font_unit_rounded</item>
```

For more details see [issue 346](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/issues/346). It's still unclear why this issue suddenly occurred with Android Studio 3.0 and only for devices with Android < 8.0. Given the random nature of this issue I assume it's a bug of the Android Gradle plugin.